# Proper grammar for "Coaches Only Apparel"?

Tags: apostrophe

What is the proper phrasing for this e-commerce shopping category?

1. Coaches Only Apparel
2. Coaches' Only Apparel
3. Coaches's Only Apparel
4. Coach's Only Apparel

Comment: Please not the site rules: "don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site: ... Naming, including naming programming variables/classes"  See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about 'naming' are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Coaches-Only Apparel" would be the correct phrasing if the category is of apparel that only coaches should purchase.

Comment: Except that 'only' does not require a capital letter!

Comment: Well, neither do "Coaches" and "Apparel", in the middle of a sentence.  But the question is asking about a *name* (i.e., a *title*) for a shopping category (or a section of a store), and "Only" is commonly capitalized in titles.